# WNetOpenEnum in Windows CE 6.0

Tags: network-programming, windows-ce

I have a problem with enumerating network resources in Windows CE 6.0. Before I call WNetEnumResource, I cannot get WNetOpenEnum work! Called this way, it returns "The parameter is incorrect". I am calling the function with lpNetResource set to NULL, because I want to start from the root. What I am doing wrong - help!

P.S. If it matters, I am debugging the OS using KITL over ethernet.

```
DWORD dwResult;
HANDLE hEnum;
LPVOID lpMsgBuf;

dwResult = WNetOpenEnum(RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, RESOURCETYPE_ANY, 0, NULL, &hEnum);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                  NULL, GetLastError(), 0, (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);
    RETAILMSG(TRUE, (L"Error in WNetOpenEnum (GUI):"));
    RETAILMSG(TRUE, ((LPWSTR)lpMsgBuf));
    LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
    return -1;
}
```